# My main goal is to create a personalized learning path for students by applying LSTM model

Tags: label, lstm, recommendation-engine

How can I effectively label students' data based on their Videos_Viewed, Difficulty_Levels of videos, and Videos_Skipped, and weekly progress also keeping in mind  that each video lecture has an assessment score which determines their progress and helps decide if recommending the next lecture is appropriate, as well as categorizing the difficulty level of each video into easy, intermediate, or hard?

I was labeling the data based on score for instance if I get score for 4 vidoes i.e {48, 65, 34, 82, 92} I would label the difficulty level as [1  Intermediate, 2  Intermediate, 3 Intermediate, 4 Hard,5 Hard].

```
if score >= 70:
            current_difficulty = "Hard"
        elif 30 <= score < 70:
            current_difficulty = "Medium"

         current_lecture += 1
        lecture_path.append(f"Lecture {current_lecture}{current_difficulty[0]} (Difficulty:      {current_difficulty})")
if current_difficulty == "Easy":
            current_lecture -= 1

    return lecture_path
```

I need to use all the categories not just the score.